# An enquiry on subtraction of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be nonconstant functions such that $1<f(x)<g(x)$.

If $f(x) < h(x)$ for all $x$, and we suppose that $g(x) \geq M$, does it follow that
                                                                                     $g(x) - f(x)> M-h(x)$ which yields $M >h(x)$ since $g(x) - f(x) > 0$ ?

Comment: Words such as *question* are uninformative in titles. Please [edit] the title so that it better describes the specifics of your question. Do not hesitate to make it longer or include a formula if needed. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(from a bot)*

Comment: Okay thanks, i hope it's better now ?

Comment: It follows that $g(x) - f(x) > M - h(x)$, but it does not follow that $M > h(x)$.

Comment: @Daniel, please explain how, since we have 2 cases namely: Case $1$: $M > h(x)$ and Case $2:$ $M\leq h(x)$. Case $2$ seems not to be possible since this would imply $f(x) \geq g(x)$, a contradiction ?

Comment: Let $g(x) = 1+\pi + e^x$, $f(x) = 1+\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan x$, $M = 1$ and $h(x) = 1+\pi$.